# elasticsearch: if i add more servers nodes can i get better query performance?

Tags: performance, elasticsearch

I am new to elasticsearch, i am testing a one node on my windows 7, i have indexed 2 millions documents, but the (match) query time is increasing, about 3 seconds (uncached) and 1.5 seconds (cached).

I would like to maintain bellow 1 second query if i go in production so my question is:

If i add more servers (nodes) can i get better query performance, supposing the hardware is good for each server and ES configuration optimized. for example if my data grows and i add n servers (nodes) does this mean that i get lower query time (below 1 second) ? is this what "scalling" mean for elasticsearch ?

here is my query (unfiltered one) i need scores too:

```
json = '{
    "from" : 0, "size" : 10,
    "query" : {
        "bool" : {
            "should": [
                { "match": { "answer_1_words": "dooms best aynol steven" }},
                { "match": { "answer_2_words": "mokrane obione kenobi zembla" }},
                { "match": { "answer_3_words": "Benghazi fake yahai tperdina" }},
                { "match": { "answer_4_words": "jackson thisisit bonzai peterpan" }},
                { "match": { "answer_5_words": "Zohra Drif mami jenaipas" }},
                { "match": { "answer_6_words": "Bon wa3lah hagda hamoud" }},
                { "match": { "answer_7_words": "cola coca petrole seule" }},
                { "match": { "answer_8_words": "dieu help salut bentley" }},
                { "match": { "answer_9_words": "edite piaf chanson merci" }},
                { "match": { "answer_10_words": "gooloom seigneur anneaux espace" }}
            ]
        }
    }
}'
```

Comment: Everything depends on your application and it's usage. Per example: search videos on Youtube is quite different than querying your local search engine for using Kabana. The ideal is to find the necessary numbers of shards by node and experimenting using a benchmarking framework such as [Tsung](http://tsung.erlang-projects.org/)

Comment: Supposing i have defined (after testing) the good configuration (shards, memory etc...), what i need to know is if i have n servers and a 3seconds query time, if i add n+5 servers (nodes) can i get query time under 3seconds, if not i can't get what's the point of scalling, expect for availability. my question is, if i have more servers does this lower my query time (performance) ?

Comment: Adding servers doesn't mean necessary improving your query time. That's why I suggested that you use a load testing tool to experimentally determine your needs because there is no rules for that. The bottleneck will always be the scheduler upon the servers

Answer (score 0):

Shards spread your data out across multiple servers allowing queries to be done in parallel, but you can't change the number of shards on an index after it's created.  If your indexes are time-based, then that's not such a bad thing since you'll be creating new indexes all of the time.

When a query comes into ES, it'll split it into however many pieces you have shards and then do a map/reduce operation on the result.  If you have multiple queries going on simultaneously, they'll be divided up among the replicas/primaries.

So if your use case is one power user making single queries at a time, you want to add shards/machines and re-index your data.  If your use case is lots of users hitting at the same time, you want to add more machines and replicas (ie this is the scale wide due to load).

You want to keep your single shard size down in the 2-4GB range... so if you are not using time series data, you'll want to allocate enough shards/machines to deal with your future data growth.

The more replicas you add though, the slower your initial indexing is going to be, so there is that trade-off.

Comment: Thank you for your help, I will have multiple users querying elasticsearch, i don't know if i add more nodes it will make my query time lower